# how to pass 2d array address to a function and write on it and print it in calling function

Tags: c, pointers, 2d

I have a function that simply takes 2d `char` array write on first element [0][0] to n and m element and in main I like to print what has been written. I only need to pass the address of entire two dimensional array and use it in calling function.

This is what I tried so far with multiple variations of tries but nothing seems to work
folloing code cause segFault

I got segFault at `array[0][0]='c';` in the called function. please note I need to pass only the address of 2d array so I can easily move around and populate the array in called function.

```
void bps(char **array,int m, int n)
{
   array[0][0]='c';
}
```

I also tried like this `*array[0]='c';` but no luck so far

I am passing array like `bps(array,x,y);` in main

this is the code in main

```
int main()
{
int x=3,y=3;
char array[3][3]={"ab","ax"};
// Or should I use like this
// char array[3][3]=(char [3][3]){"ab","ax"};
bps(array,x,y);
printf("%c",array[0][0]);
return 0;
}
```

or should I use like this in bps(..)

```
void bps(char *array,int m, int n )
{
   *(*(array))='c';
}
```

please clarify

Comment: Maybe you could share the piece of code calling the bps function?

Comment: We need to see the code in `main`. See [mcve].

Comment: ok I am posting it thanks for comments

Comment: @user3386109 please see my updated question

Comment: No `type var[n][m]` will *ever* be compatible with `type **var`.  One is an array of arrays of `type` , the other a pointer to pointer to `type`. If your platform supports variable-length arrays you can use `void bps(int m, int n, char array[m][n])` for your function. The order of those arguments is important, btw.

Comment: If your platform doesn't support variable-length arrays, then in `main`, you can create an array of pointers: `char *ptrs[3] = {array[0], array[1], array[2]};` Then pass that to the function: `bps(ptrs, x, y)`

Comment: @WhozCraig `If your platform supports variable-length arrays you can use void bps(int m, int n, char array[][n]) for your function` can u explain what does this mean? does it mean first dimensional can be variable length like `array[this is variable length dimension][this is fixed]` so basically ur function signature works pretty well. I tried. so does it mean my system can handle only one dimensional variable length so I am good with this `void bps(int m, int n, char array[][n])` on my `x86-64` processor. what about raspberry pi processor that runs Linux. can u please add the model name too

Comment: @user3386109 ur last comment seems very interesting. thanks

Comment: This should never seg fault if the compiler is compliant and you are paying attention to warnings. A conforming compiler must give a message regarding incompatible pointer types. I strongly recommend beginners to compile with maximum diagnostics, strict conformance and set all warnings as errors. On gcc, clang or icc that means `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Answer (score 0):

`char**` may be used for 1D arrays of pointers, such as pointing in the first item in an array of strings. But it cannot be used to point at a 2D array. Forget that you ever heard of `type**` in relation to 2D arrays.

Change `void bps(char **array,int m, int n)` to:

```
void bps (int m, int n, char array[m][n])
```

Access individual items with `array[i][j]`, not with obscure and unreadable pointer arithmetic like `*(*(array))='c';`.

---

Detailed explanation:

The reason why `char array[m][n]` works is that arrays, whenever used as a function parameter, get implicitly adjusted ("decays") to a pointer to their first element by the compiler.

Given an array `char array[m][n]`, it is an array of arrays. The first item is therefore an array of type `char[n]`. A pointer to that first item type is written as `char (*)[n]`. Therefore

```
void bps (int m, int n, char array[m][n])
```

is 100% equivalent to

```
void bps (int m, int n, char (*array)[n])
```

And in either case the array is passed "by reference", not by value as one might incorrectly suspect.